# Matrix - Super Admin only columns?

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

Has this been done before?
I'm in a situation where I need a column hidden from content managers and only visible to the super admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not core functionality for Matrix.

You would need to either write a custom extension that would hide the column from non Super Admins or find another add-on to help.

One possible solution is to use the [Securit:ee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/securitee) add-on's encryption fieldtype, which allows you to configure which member groups can view the unencrypted data in a field. If you used this fieldtype for your column, then it should only allow the groups you specify to see the data. Of course this is contingent upon your column being a text field and not some other fieldtype.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realise it's not the standard functionality, I was more hoping that someone might have needed to do this before and written a little extension to get it done. But I can't find anything, so it looks like I might have to do something for myself :)  when I do, I'll share it.